# AsyncTask : onPostExecute() runs before doInBackground()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Following is an asynctask to download a file from firebase. I'm using some global variables inside my asynctask. But from the output it's clear that `onPostExecute()` is finishing execution before `doInBackground()` finishes.

```
class downloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
                            if (selectedItems.get(i) == 1) {

                                DatabaseReference Ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("modules").child("items").child(item.getNumber() + "");
                                Ref.removeValue();

                                Log.e("new2","2");
                                Ref.setValue(item);
                                //Log.e("new2",item.getLink());

                                finish();
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                        StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
                        StorageReference riversRef = storageRef.child("modules/"+mediaUri.getLastPathSegment());
                        UploadTask uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(mediaUri);

                        // Register observers to listen for when the download is done or if it fails
                        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                Log.e("download fail","fail");
                            }
                        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                                fileUrl=downloadUrl.toString();
                                Log.e("new0","fileurl is "+fileUrl);
                                item.setLink(fileUrl);
                                Log.e("new1",item.getLink());


                            }
                        });

                        return null;
                    }
                }

                (new downloadTask()).execute();
```

In the log output for this, the Log statement from `onPostExecute()` is printed before the log statement from `doInBackground()` . Hence I can say that `onPostExecute()` is executing first.
    How do I fix this?

Comment: Firebase itself is asynchronous. Asynctask is well documented to only run onPostExecute after doInBackground. Do you need an Asynctask?

Comment: Because you return null and not the actual response. You are not waiting for the status at all.

Comment: In other words, your claims are false. Put a log statement before `addOnFailureListener`, then try to tell us what is  running first

Answer (score 1):

That's a wrong assumption. doInBackground() does actually finish *before* onPostExecute(). The problem is, that you do other ansynchronous stuff inside doInBackground() as well. So once you added the OnFailureListener and OnSuccessListener, doInBackground() finishes and onPostExecute() is invoked. However, you get the callbacks of your listeners later than that.

So actually you don't need an AsyncTask because your uploadTask is already asychrounous.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem in getting data from firebase using *AsyncTask* class. I noticed that onPostExecute method runs before I am getting the data from database. I tried to implement a class to get data from firebase and notify me with a listener once data is received rather that using onPostExecute() method. Using AsyncTask might be redundant because Firebase methods are them self asynchronous but AysingTask object gives more flexibility in case of adding progress dialogs and staff like that. This class is also helpful if you have multiple calls to read from firebase. you don't need to write code multiple times. here is my class:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;


public class FirebaseDataCenter {

    // this is a class to deal with the database

    private DataFetcher fetcher;

    public FirebaseDataCenter(){
        // empty constructor
    }

    public void readFromDatabase(DatabaseReference databaseReference, OnDataReceived listener){
        fetcher = new DataFetcher();
        fetcher.setDataBaseReference(databaseReference);
        fetcher.onDataRecieved(listener);
        fetcher.execute();
    }



    private class DataFetcher extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private DatabaseReference dataref;
        private OnDataReceived listener;

        public void setDataBaseReference(DatabaseReference dataref){
            this.dataref = dataref;
        }

        public DatabaseReference getDataRef(){
            return dataref;
        }

        public void onDataRecieved(OnDataReceived listener){
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        public OnDataReceived getListener(){
            return this.listener;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            getData();
            return null;
        }

        public void getData() {
            dataref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    listener.gotData(dataSnapshot.getChildren()); // this listener will hold your Datasnapshot object for further manipulation in your class
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void voids) {
            super.onPostExecute(voids);
        }
    }
}

interface OnDataReceived {
    void gotData(Iterable<DataSnapshot> data);
    // this is an interface working as a listener when the data is retrieved.
}
```

To use that class you need to write only this lines:

```
FirebaseDataCenter fetcher = new FirebaseDataCenter();
        fetcher.readFromDatabase(yourFirebaseReferencePath, new OnDataReceived() {
            @Override
            public void gotData(final Iterable<DataSnapshot> data) {
                  // do whatever you need with the DataSnapshot you recieved from this listener. Notice that this DataSnapshot object is iterable!! 
            }
         });
```

Hope this help,, :)